string matching within a single column elements
locality <- c(
  "14- Rajpur Road", "14 Block Gurudwara Park", "142 Katra", "15 Taj Enclave",
  "18 Quarter Vivek Vihar", "60 Feet Road Vishwas Nagar", "60 Foota Road",
  "A- Block Meethapur Extn. Shree Colony", "A-Block Majlis Park", "A & E Block",
  "A Block Krishna Nagar", "A&B Block", "A.G.C.R (Karkad Doma)",
  "Aali Extn. Block A", "Aali Extn. Block B",
  "Aali Vihar -(Block A B C D E F G & H )", "Aali Village Extended Abadi",
  "Aanad Colony", "Aashiyana Apartment", "Aasirwad Apartments",
  "Aasirwad Enclave Apartment", "Aaya Nagar Extn. Ph-I",
  "ABD Block , Preet Vihar", "Abul Fazal Enclave", "Abul Fazal Enclave (Main)",
  "Abul Fazal Enclave Block-E to N", "Abul Fazal Enclave Pt-II",
  "Abul Fazal Enclave Pt-II Block G", "Abul Fazal Enclave Pt-II Block H",
  "Acharya Niketan", "Adarsh Basti Mohd Pur", "Adarsh Bhawan CHBS",
  "Adarsh Enclave", "Adarsh Enclave (Y-Block)", "Adarsh Laxmi Vihar",
  "Adarsh Mandi Loni Jila", "Adarsh Nagar", "Adarsh Nagar Extn.",
  "Adarsh Trilokya Apartments", "Adchini", "Adhchini", "AGCR",
  "AcharayaNiketan"
)

locality <- as.data.frame(locality)

This is an example of few localities out of 6000 in a single column. I would like to extract the best similar match for each row element based on string match. I would like another column with the similar names from the same column corresponding to each element of the row.
How can I implement it. I have tried all possible posts but have not found a solution.

Please add the expected output.
